# Subdomain URL Redirect dynamically. .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-routing

I want redirect url using .htaccess
like.

**abc.website.com to website.com/folder/abc
http://abc.website.com to http://www.website.com/folder/abc**

using **.htaccess** from PHP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|webmail|help|whm|root)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.website.com
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website.com/folder/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: in case www, whm,root,webmail,mail,help case i don't want to redirect.

Comment: @M.Nadeem Man, why didn't bring those up when asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.website.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/folder/abc/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

For a more general rule (that works with any subdomain, not just sub) replace the last two lines with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.abc.website\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/folder/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I hope it will work for you.